# How to export variable from node js(commonjs) to normal javascript( vanilla js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i am creating an express project where i have some variables which needed to be passed in
raw javascript(placed in folder static)

my express project name app.js
my raw javascript file index.js

lets say i want to export variable x = 10;

i did

```
//app.js
var fs  = require("fs");
//my express code 
const x = 10;     
module.exports = x;
```

now my normal javascript file

```
  //index.js
  import "../app.js"
  window.alert(x)// how to alert x in window
```

my views html

```
 <script src=./static/index.js ></script>
```

// please also explain any turaround if any
//i read all the questions but didnt find one answering my question in simple terms

how to do it?

Comment: yes , spelling mistake corrected...is there any turn around , at some posts they use babel?